# Tidymodels Recipe Package Use step_normalize On List Of Variables

Tags: r, machine-learning, recipe, tidymodels

I want to normalize only an arbitrary selection of variables using step_normalize from the recipe package (tidymodels). Unfortunately I can't find a selection function that seems to work within the step_normalize which selects a list of variables:

```
library(tidymodels)
iris %>% 
  recipe(Species ~ .) %>% 
  step_normalize(vars_select(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length)) %>% 
  prep()
```

I get this error message:

```
Error: Not all functions are allowed in step function selectors (e.g. `vars_select`). See ?selections.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`step_normalize` does not support this select helper function, this works:

```
iris %>% 
  recipe(Species ~ .) %>% 
  step_normalize(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length) %>% 
  prep()
```

See `?selections` for supported selector functions.